# facebook share image is not showing on facebook via android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to facebook integration, i've been working on this several days now and i believe i will be able to fix this. My problem is, the image i attached for share dialog is not showing on facebook.

[image]

and here is my code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] bookCover;
LayoutInflater inflater;
```

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

```
    final PdfHandler pdf = new PdfHandler(context);
    final int pdfPos = position;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    //imgflag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imgflag.setImageResource(bookCover[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViefeewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    imgflag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int data = bookCover[position];

            shareImage(data);

        }
    });

    return itemView;
}



public void shareImage(int data) {
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putInt("picture", data );

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(context,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(context, 
                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(context, 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Error posting story", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }



            })
            .build();
        feedDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Feed Dialog or Feed Graph API you can not pass the image data in `picture`. So you should provide a url instead of data.

Just a trick- you can first upload a picture using `/photos` where you can use the image data, then you can use this image url into the feed.

Hop it help. Good luck!